# How to reduce latency while reading data from csv file?

Tags: python

I have an excel in which there are 2000 rows which contains 1 data each, like

a.xls

```
RowNum    Item 
1          'A'
2          'B'
3          'C'
.
.
.
2000      'xyz'
```

I have another file, `b.xls` which contains about 6300000 rows of data. In this file there are some occurrences of the data in `a.xls` . I need to pick all the  data from the file `b.xls` corresponding to an item in `a.xls` and store them in separate file called `A.csv`, `B.csv`, etc

I did it using multi-threading but it's taking lots of time to execute it. Can anybody help me reducing the latency?

This is the code I have used. The following function gets started in a thread,

```
def parseFromFile(pTickerList):
    global gSearchList

    lSearchList = gSearchList

    for lTickerName in pTickerList:
        c = csv.writer( open("op-new/"+ lTickerName + ".csv", "wb"))
        c.writerow(["Ticker Name", "Time Stamp","Price", "Size"])

        for line in lSearchList:
            lSplittedLine = line.split(",")
            lTickerNameFromSearchFile = lSplittedLine[0].strip()

            if lTickerNameFromSearchFile[0] == "#":
                continue

            if ord(lTickerName[0]) < ord(lTickerNameFromSearchFile[0]):
                break
            elif ord(lTickerName[0]) > ord(lTickerNameFromSearchFile[0]):
                continue

            if lTickerNameFromSearchFile == lTickerName:
                lTimeStamp = Decimal(float(lSplittedLine[1]))
                lPrice = lSplittedLine[2]
                lSize = lSplittedLine[4]


                    if str(lTimeStamp)[len(str(lTimeStamp))-2:] == "60":
                        lTimeStamp = str(lTimeStamp)[:len(str(lTimeStamp))-2] + "59.9"

                    if str(lTimeStamp).find(".") >= 0:
                        lTimeStamp = float(str(lTimeStamp).split(".")[0] + "." + str(lTimeStamp).split(".")[1][0])
                        lTimeStamp1 = "%.1f" %float(lTimeStamp)
                        lHumanReadableTimeStamp = datetime.strptime(str(lTimeStamp1), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f")
                    else:
                        lHumanReadableTimeStamp = datetime.strptime(str(lTimeStamp), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

                except Exception, e:
                    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
                    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]      
                    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
                    print line
                    print lTimeStamp
                    raw_input()

                c.writerow([lTickerNameFromSearchFile, lHumanReadableTimeStamp,lPrice, lSize])
```

Comment: And what is the code you used then? Did you use nested loops perhaps?

Comment: If the searches are being done on in-memory lists or dictionaries, then you will fall foul of the GIL, which means only one of the threads is running at a time. You can get around this with multiprocessing, or IPython.parallel, etc.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters I have mentioned the code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to look through your code and fully understand it because it's referencing variables differently than your explanation, but I believe this approach will help you.

Start by reading all of `a.csv` into a `set` with the traits you want to be able to look up. `sets` in Python have very fast lookup times. This will also help you because it seems a that you do a lot of repeat computation during your inner loop from your code above.

Then start reading through `b.csv`, using the previous `a.csv set` to check. Whenever you find a match, write to `A.csv` and `B.csv`.

The big speedups you can do to your current setup are removing the repeat calculations in your inner loop, and the removal of the need for threads. Because `a.csv` is only 2000 lines, it will be incredibly fast to read.

Let me know if you want me to expand on any part of this.

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir, but how can I remove the repeat calculation?

Comment: I suppose this mostly comes from my confusuion between this is `a.csv` and which is `b.csv` ... which one is lSearchList / gSearchList?